# How best to determine student improvement before and after multiple tests?

Tags: independence, pre-post-comparison

I have the following situation in my hands: I have 13 students who have undergone skills training. Their performance has been evaluated on a scale of 0-100 using 14 different exercises, before and after their training. I can do paired t-test analysis for every individual exercise, but is there a statistically proper way for me to evaluate overall improvement across all 14 exercise results? Just to be clear, every student has only two scores per exercise, before and after, which amounts to 14 before and 14 after training scores for each one of them.

I could just bin all the pre- and post-training scores for all 14 exercises together and run a paired t-test on that, but it somehow feels wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a multilevel model, allowing you to evaluate mean improvement on the exercises over time, as well as the individual students' improvements:

```
> ## Generate some example data:
> set.seed(42)
> student_id <- rep(factor(1:13), each = 14)
> exercise <- rep(factor(1:14), times = 13)
> occasion <- factor(rep(0:1, each = 13*14))
> pre_means <- rnorm(13, mean = 50)
> pre <- round(rep(pre_means, each = 14) + rnorm(13*14))
> post <- round(rep(pre_means, each = 14) + rep(rnorm(13, mean = 10), each = 14) + 
+                 rnorm(13*14))
> data <- data.frame(student_id, occasion, result = c(pre, post))
> head(data)
  student_id occasion result
1          1        0     51
2          1        0     51
3          1        0     52
4          1        0     51
5          1        0     49
6          1        0     49
> tail(data)
    student_id occasion result
359         13        1     57
360         13        1     57
361         13        1     57
362         13        1     58
363         13        1     59
364         13        1     58
```

Fit a multilevel model and inspect results:

```
> library("lme4")
> mod <- lmer(result ~ occasion + (occasion | student_id), data = data)
> summary(mod)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: result ~ occasion + (occasion | student_id)
   Data: data

REML criterion at convergence: 1106.9

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.9752 -0.6869 -0.0289  0.7411  3.4557 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 student_id (Intercept) 1.3601   1.1662       
            occasion1   1.4492   1.2038   0.23
 Residual               0.9892   0.9946       
Number of obs: 364, groups:  student_id, 13

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  50.5275     0.3317  152.31
occasion1    10.1374     0.3498   28.98

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
          (Intr)
occasion1 0.169
```

The fixed intercept gives us the mean performance at the pre assessment (fixed effect `(Intercept)`). The fixed slope gives us the mean increase in score over time (fixed effect `occasion1`). Thus, on average, the students scores 50.53 at the pre assessment, and 50.53+10.14=60.67 at the post assessment.

I also included a random intercept and slope w.r.t. student through specification of `(occasion | student_id)`. This allows us to evaluate the deviation of each student from the means at the pre and post assessments:

```
> ranef(mod)
$student_id
   (Intercept)  occasion1
1   0.63710704  1.0109655
2  -1.27956242  0.2978854
3   0.07244512  0.5224094
4   0.43161216  0.9322671
5  -0.15613902  0.0578274
6  -0.55199220 -2.0837120
7   1.12865296  0.2775566
8  -0.96452167  1.0888319
9   1.42650490  1.8997896
10 -0.78622053 -1.5240657
11  0.51396430 -1.0470807
12  1.73538894 -0.7678323
13 -2.20723960 -0.6648423

with conditional variances for “student_id” 
> coef(mod)
$student_id
   (Intercept) occasion1
1     51.16458 11.148328
2     49.24791 10.435248
3     50.59992 10.659772
4     50.95908 11.069630
5     50.37133 10.195190
6     49.97548  8.053651
7     51.65613 10.414919
8     49.56295 11.226195
9     51.95398 12.037152
10    49.74125  8.613297
11    51.04144  9.090282
12    52.26286  9.369530
13    48.32023  9.472520

attr(,"class")
[1] "coef.mer"
```

The result of `ranef` provides the deviation of each student from the fixed effects. The result of `coef` provides the fixed effects, added to the students' deviations from it. Thus, student `7` scored 1.13 above the mean at the pre assessment, and 0.28 above the mean at the post assessment, corresponding to a mean score of 51.66 at the pre assessment, and the mean score having increased with 10.41 at the post assessment.

Further possibilities:

- You could also estimate the difficulty of the exercises, and have students' ability estimates corrected for the difficulty of the exercises. This would be similar to a Rasch model (although you have a continuous response for each exercise, and in a Rasch model the response is dichotomous). See e.g, https://www.jamesuanhoro.com/post/2018/01/02/using-glmer-to-perform-rasch-analysis/  (section Multilevel logistic regression or MML; you can just replace `glmer` with `lmer`).
- The exercises are scored 1-100, if this is a percentage, a beta regression might be more appropriate. For multilevel beta regression, see e.g., [Model Assumptions: LMER / GLMER Model where Dependent Variable is a Percentage](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143165/model-assumptions-lmer-glmer-model-where-dependent-variable-is-a-percentage)

Comment: Thank you for your time; these scores are from 0-100, so yes, they could be treated as percentages. How would I go about setting up a multilevel model or a beta regression in SPSS?

Comment: @flareman I rarely if ever use SPSS. I know you can do beta regression and multilevel models in SPSS, but I'm not sure if you can do multilevel beta regression.

Comment: I finally went with multilevel modeling in SPSS; I was able to come to some interesting conclusions. Thanks!

Comment: @flareman Excellent! Happy to help!